# How to get db.currentOp() from C# driver - mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to monitor mongoServer including running process and its during time.

Is there any way to get db.currentOp() in C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google could probably answer this question... How about `GetCurrentOp`?

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var server = client.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase("test", WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
var currentOp = db.GetCurrentOp();
```

Comment: I tried this against various databases (local v2.6 without auth and and remote v3.01 servers with auth) using the v2.0 driver and I get an `MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException` with an inner `System.IO.EndOfStreamException`. Same when I try `db.GetCollection("$cmd.sys.inprog").FindOne()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using the 2.0 driver:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("$cmd.sys.inprog");
var currentOp = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).FirstOrDefault();
```

After updating our MongoDB instance to 3.4.10 (from 3.0), the previous answer no longer worked for me. Here's what I had to update it to:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:password@localhost?authSource=admin");
var db = client.GetDatabase("admin");
var command = new BsonDocument {
    { "currentOp", "1"},
};
var currentOp = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```