# How to kill a long queries from C# Driver - mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wrote a c# program that works with MongoDB.

It finds [long time running queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451022/how-to-get-db-currentop-from-c-sharp-driver-mongodb) but I can not kill them. I googled so much but I didn't find anything useful.

Can anyone help me with killing the queries?

Answer (score 1):

You must use [killOp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) to stop the query

With your driver you may try something like this

```
var db = server.GetDatabase("test", WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
var currentOp = db.GetCurrentOp();
var opid = ... fetch from currentOp result
db.RunCommand(new CommandDocument("killOp", opid));
```

Comment: Not works :(  ###  
Additional information: Command 'killOp' failed: no such cmd: killOp (response: { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: killOp" })